# How to save dynamic text in a frame so that the text will appear when back to the frame?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a dynamic text in a frame 1. Let say the instance of the dynamic text is myText. The text in the dynamic text will be changed depends on the some events. I provide a button to go to the next frame and provide another button to back to frame 1 (using prevFrame() and nextFrame() )
what I want is when we back to the frame 1, the text in dynamic text before we leave frame 1 will still there.

I've tried to save the text in dynamic text in an array, but when I 'click' the button to go back to frame 1 [usinf prevFrame()], the content in the array is empty, but if I have a button in other frame and tried to trace the array, the text is in it..

am I doing this correctly? or any idea how to do this?

thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you reinialize the array when enter into frame 1.
Make a global var and check for undefined when set it's value;
i.e.
var txt;
if ( undefined == txt  )
{
txt = "Text";
}

Answer (score 0):

On btn1.press do

```
foo=myText.text
nextFrame
```

On btn2.press do

```
prevFrame
if (foo!=undefined)
    myText.text = foo
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably initializing the array in the frame 1. Check if the array is already initialized and don't initialize if it already is. I assume you have something like this in the first frame `var arr = new Array();`, so you need to add the check

```
if(arr == null)
  arr = new Array();
```